Bootstrap nav bar not working in Next JS 14
Please check following URL - https://github.com/omkarpuranik/next-blog
Bootstrap navbar dropdown and mobile menu not working. I have installed bootstrap via npm and trying to access JS file for some features.
Layout.tsx -
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "@/app/components/header";
import BootstrapClient from "@/app/components/bootstrapclient";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <BootstrapClient />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

BootstrapClient.tsx  -
'use client';

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function BootstrapClient(){
    useEffect(()=>{
        //@ts-ignore
        import("@popperjs/core/dist/esm/popper.js");
        //@ts-ignore
        import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js");
    })
    return(<></>);
}


Bootstrap bundle already contains Popper. Loading a library twice can cause issues like this.
